# Changing turtle cursor shape using Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there a simple way to change the turtle cursor to an open hand and back to normal cursor? I have searched and did not find a thing. I'm using Python turtle on Windows.

Comment: You will need an external library. Try looking into pygame (https://pygame.org)

Comment: Please indicate what platform or UI framework you are using. Is this a web or desktop app? Linux, Windows, or MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

There are few preset shapes for turtle such as, arrow, circle, etc. You can find them here https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.shape, or you could use the turtle.register_shape(image_name) function. Hope this helps!

Comment: The OP's desire "open hand" is not one of the predefined turtle cursor shapes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple way to change the cursor to an open hand and back to
>   normal cursor?

Yes, you first want the `register_shape()` method of the screen, passing it your GIF file name.  Then you pass the same file name to the `shape()` method of turtle.  (Newer implementations of turtle and tkinter accept more file types but traditionally this needs to be a GIF.)

Demonstrating with a [guinea pig GIF found on iconsplace.com](https://iconsplace.com/black-icons/guinea-pig-icon/), the following code switches from the turtle cursor that comes with the Python library to a guinea pig cursor from that site when you click on the window:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

IMAGE = "guinea-pig-icon-24.gif"

def change(x, y):
    turtle.shape(IMAGE)

screen = Screen()
screen.register_shape(IMAGE)

turtle = Turtle('turtle')

screen.onclick(change)
screen.mainloop()
```

Switching back again is simple as calling the `shape()` method again.